# Appium: How to write for-loop to click through buttons with index?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, appium, winappdriver

I am using C# and Appium to automate a Windows 10 software for my company. On the bookmarks bar, there is a list of tabs that I want to click through. They are buttons that are indexed from 15-20. Rather than doin

```
driver.FindElementsByXpath("//Pane/Button[15]").Click();

driver.FindElementsByXpath("//Pane/Button[16]").Click();

driver.FindElementsByXpath("//Pane/Button[17]").Click();

driver.FindElementsByXpath("//Pane/Button[18]").Click();

driver.FindElementsByXpath("//Pane/Button[19]").Click();
```

and so on, how can I write a for loop that will loop through and click `onbutton[15]` to `button[30]`? Is this even possible with Appium? Thanks!

Comment: Where  is the problem? Don't you know how to do loop or what?

Comment: Hi, you might consider rechecking your tags again. I think Java in this case might not really be so helpful if you use appium the people on StackOverflow I think know enough ;)

Comment: @Selvin I am using C# not Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I should have put the WindowsElement line in side the for loop. Probably not the most optimal solution, but it does what I want it to. Thanks everyone. Also thanks @Selvin for the roast.

```
for(int i=15; i<=30; i++)
        {
            WindowsElement buttons = FBsession.FindElementsByXPath("//Pane/Button")[i];
            buttons.Click();
        }
```